# Can't add local image to react native app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react & I'm trying to add a local image to my react app. This is what i've currently, `<Image source={require("images/pic.jpeg")} />`

but cant figure out why am i getting this error.

`ERROR 00:24 Unable to resolve "images/pic.jpeg" from "App.js"`

I've installed the Image component also, and have made a separate images folder. I'm using iOS simulator.

If someone could help me regarding this, it would be great!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. You are requiring image with absolute path, which is more likely the reason it
   is not importing properly.

> <Image source={require('./images/pic.jpeg')} />

Please pass the pass which you have in your folder structure
and require path would be like above example, with `./` or `../`

2. Another solution to import image source is to obtain image source url.

> import picImage from '../../assets/images/pic.jpeg';

and pass this picImage as src value

```
 <Image source={picImage} />
```

Comment: @ishasharmax Can you please accept this answer if it works for you?